# Dynamic table rowspan in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html-table

Has anybody tried dynamic table rowspan in vue.js?

Below is data

```
{
    date: '2018-08-14',
    temp_que : 120,
},
{
    date: '2018-08-14',
    temp_que : 120,
},
{
    date: '2018-08-15',
    temp_que : 120,
},
{
    date: '2018-08-15',
    temp_que : 120,
},
```

Below is html vue

```
<template v-for="(item, i) in list">
  <tr> 
    <td
      :rowspan=""
      v-if=""
      class="text-center"
      v-text="item.date"
    ></td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

Question is how I put rowspan when date got same date?

Answer (score 8):

First,you need to count the number of same date, 
like this:
   {
    date: '2018-08-14',
    same_num:'count',
    temp_que : 120,
    },

```
  <template >
     <tr v-for="(item, i) in list"> 
       <td
         :rowspan="item.same_num"
         v-if="!i? true:item[i-1].date==item[i].date? '':true"
         class="text-center"
         v-text="item.date"
       ></td>
     </tr>
   </template>
```

Comment: '!i?' make sure 'i>0',so item[i-1] is valid.'list' must be a Array