# How can i make this dynamic rowspan in vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm trying to make a table that will looks like the image below.

[image]

I know that I can do it with nested data using a multiple iteration with the use of `template` provided by vuetify. And it also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64492923/how-to-use-dynamic-table-rowspan-in-vue-js).

Also I can do it with just normal data that have not more than two data just like example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53258389/dynamic-table-rowspan-in-vue-js)

But, the data i'm receiving is not from nested data nor just two data. I'm receiving more than five columns with multiple duplicated data.

So I'm trying to figure out what would be the index and what length should I use for the rowspan of my table.

Is there's a way to know the index and remove duplicated data and make as one or make a rowspan with this kind of table?

[Here the sample Code.](https://codepen.io/neyubee/pen/yLGOvyN)

Comment: Please post your code and the data directly in the question instead of a link, see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

rowspan sits on the first row, so I would calculate for each item where a value first appears how many rows it needs to span. The result would look something like this:

```
const rows = [
  {val1: 'a', val1Rowspan: 3}, // first appearance of value, has rowspan
  {val1: 'a'}, // same value as above, no rowspan
  {val1: 'a'}, // same value as above, no rowspan
  {val1: 'b', val1Rowspan: 1},
  {val1: 'c', val1Rowspan: 2},
  {val1: 'c'},
]
```

This works nicely with v-for:

```html
<table>
  <tr v-for="row of rows">
    <td
      v-if="row.val1Rowspan"
      :rowspan="row.val1Rowspan"
    >{{ row.val1 }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const App = { 
  template: `
    <table>
  <tr v-for="(row, index) of rows">
    <td>{{index}}</td>
    <td
      v-if="row.val1Rowspan"
      :rowspan="row.val1Rowspan"
    >{{ row.val1 }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
    rows:   [
      {val1: 'a', val1Rowspan: 3},
      {val1: 'a'},
      {val1: 'a'},
      {val1: 'b', val1Rowspan: 1},
      {val1: 'c', val1Rowspan: 2},
      {val1: 'c'},
    ]
    }  
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

Calculating the rowspans is quite easy with a nested loop, the outer loop sets the current value, the inner loop counts the elements with the same value, then the count is set as rowspan and the outer loop jumps to the first element with the next value. You have to do this for each column using rowspan.

Does that make sense, does it work for you?